# Express/connect 'connect.sid' session cookie not created windows 10

Tags: windows, session, cookies, express

I have an express web app that uses express-session with connect-redis to create and store sessions and send session cookies back to the browser. This works fine (and has worked fine for 2+ years) on all machines. Windows 10, however, has introduced something that prevents the connect.sid session cookie from being created -- for ALL browsers (chrome, IE, Edge).

This of course prevents users from being able to log into my site, because a session is never created nor held. I've checked my authentication route and it seems to work fine in the Windows 10 env (the creds are correctly sent to the server and validated against the database) but the connect.sid session cookie doesn't exists and therefore the browser doesn't know the user has been authenticated on subsequent page loads. I re-emphasize, this has worked fine for years, and only fails in all browsers running on Windows 10 machines.

Does anybody know why this is / how to fix this?

Comment: @Ragnar seems like an unrelated problem. This was explicitly caused by a our code not sending the cookie when the userAgent didn't match a mobile or desktop browser (and for some reason IE doesn't register as either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is *generally* not an actual issue. We had the following block in our code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.useragent.isDesktop || req.useragent.isMobile) {
    sessionMiddleware(req, res, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

So the only interesting lesson to learn here is that express's interpretation of the windows 10 useragent strings fails to recognize it as anything at all:

```
{ 
  isMobile: false,
  isiPad: false,
  isiPod: false,
  isiPhone: false,
  isAndroid: false,
  isBlackberry: false,
  isOpera: false,
  isIE: false,
  isIECompatibilityMode: false,
  isSafari: false,
  isFirefox: false,
  isWebkit: false,
  isChrome: true,
  isKonqueror: false,
  isOmniWeb: false,
  isSeaMonkey: false,
  isFlock: false,
  isAmaya: false,
  isEpiphany: false,
  isDesktop: false,
  isWindows: false,
  isLinux: false,
  isLinux64: false,
  isMac: false,
  isBada: false,
  isSamsung: false,
  isRaspberry: false,
  isBot: false,
  isCurl: false,
  isAndroidTablet: false,
  isWinJs: false,
  isKindleFire: false,
  isSilk: false,
  SilkAccelerated: false,
  Browser: 'Chrome',
  Version: '44.0.2403.155',
  OS: 'unknown',
  Platform: 'Microsoft Windows',
  GeoIP: {},
  source: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36'
}
```